# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined - fineuploader v4.0.3

Tags: jquery, fine-uploader

I'm getting this error after upgrading from fineuploader v4.0.0 to v4.0.3. I'm using the s3.jquery.fineuploader-4.0.3.js file and jquery version 1.8.3. There error is on line 9600 on this function -

```
$.fn.fineUploaderS3 = function(optionsOrCommand) {
    if (typeof optionsOrCommand === 'object') {

        // This option is used to tell the plug-in wrapper to instantiate the appropriate S3-namespace modules.
        optionsOrCommand.endpointType = "s3";
    }

    return $.fn.fineUploader.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

Its not liking my dom selector? Not sure what's causing it. When I downgrade back to 4.0.0, everything is all good. Any hints?

Below is my js file in all its glory -

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function check_for_uploads() {
        var uploads = $fineUploader.fineUploader("getUploads");
        var uploading = 0;
        $.each(uploads, function(index, val) {
            if (val.status == "uploading") {
                uploading++;
            }
        });

        console.log('check for uploads '+uploading);
        return uploading;
    }

    function get_net_uploads() {
        var totalUploads = $fineUploader.fineUploader("getNetUploads");
        console.log('get net uploads '+totalUploads);
        return totalUploads;
    }

    function uploads_done() {
        //close modal
        $("#uploadMediaModal").modal("hide");
        //refresh media index
        $('#mediaArea').load($('#mediaIndex').attr('href'));
        //clear upload modal
        $('#fineUploader').html("");
        //reset upload modal close button
        $(".upload-video-cancel-btn").prop("disabled", false);
        $(".upload-video-cancel-btn").button('reset');
        //show success banner
        $(".alert-success").remove();
        $(".alert-error").remove();
        $(".projects").prepend('<div id="flashMessage" class="alert alert-success"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>Your videos have been uploaded successfully!</div>');

    }

    function check_file_size(id) {
        //check the file size and if over 500mb, throw a warning somewhere
        $filesize = $fineUploader.fineUploader("getSize", id);
        console.log('File size '+$filesize);
        return $filesize;
    }

    function video_submitted() {
        //file has been submitted to us
        console.log("Video submitted");
        //disable close button on the upload modal
        $(".upload-video-cancel-btn").prop("disabled", true);
        $(".upload-video-cancel-btn").button("loading");

        //open the upload modal. prevent user from closing it
        $('#uploadMediaModal').modal({
          backdrop: 'static',
          show: true
        });
    }

    function reset_upload_modal_button(showflash) {
        $(".upload-video-cancel-btn").prop("disabled", false);
        $(".upload-video-cancel-btn").button('reset');
        if (showflash) {
            //show success banner
            $(".alert-success").remove();
            $(".alert-error").remove();
            $(".projects").prepend('<div id="flashMessage" class="alert alert-success"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>Your videos have been uploaded successfully!</div>');
        }
    }

    $fineUploader = $('.video-dropzone').fineUploaderS3({
        request: {
            endpoint: "*REMOVED*",
            accessKey: "*REMOVED"
        },
        listElement: document.getElementById('fineUploader'),
        signature: {
            endpoint: "/media/signs3url"
        },
        chunking: {
            enabled: true
        },
        resume: {
            enabled: true
        },
        failedUploadTextDisplay: {
            mode: 'custom'
        },
        retry: {
            enableAuto: true,
            showAutoRetryNote: false,
            maxAutoAttempts: 30
        },
        camera : {
            ios: true
        },
        validation: {
            allowedExtensions: ['3g2','3gp','3gp2','3gpp','3gpp2','aac','ac3', 'avi', 'eac3','ec3','f4a','f4b','f4v','flv','highwinds','m4a','m4b','m4r','m4v','mkv','mov','mp3','mp4','oga','ogg','ogv','ogx','ts','webm','wma','wmv'],
            sizelimit: 2147483648 //2gb
        },
        showMessage: function(message) {
            //show message in the upload modal if its open
            if ($('#fineUploader').hasClass("in")) {
                $('#fineUploader').prepend('<div id="flashMessage" class="alert alert-error"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>'+message+'</div>');
                //console.log('There was an error :'+message);
            } else {
                $('.projects').prepend('<div id="flashMessage" class="alert alert-error"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>'+message+'</div>');
            }
        },
        uploadSuccess: {
            endpoint: '/media/add/'+projectId+'' //projectId defined on media index
        },
        debug: true
    }).on('error', function (event, id, name, errorReason, xhrOrXdr) {
        //bomb the whole process
        //$fileItem = $(this).fineUploader("getItemByFileId", id);
        //$fileItem.find(".progress").removeClass("active").removeClass("progress-info").removeClass("progress-striped").addClass("progress-error");
        //alert(qq.format("Error on file number {} - {}.  Reason: {}", id, name, errorReason));
        //$("#fineUploader").prepend('<div id="flashMessage" class="alert alert-error"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>Error on file <b>'+name+'</b>. Error: '+errorReason+'</div>');
        console.log('There was an error :'+errorReason);
    }).on('complete', function (event, id, name, response) {
        console.log('Complete callback called on id: '+id+'. Response was: '+JSON.stringify(response));
        //remove active class from progress bar. remove cancel button from filename
        $fileItem = $(this).fineUploader("getItemByFileId", id);
        $fileName = $fineUploader.fineUploader("getName", id);
        if (response.success) {
            $fileItem.find(".progress").removeClass("active").removeClass("progress-info").removeClass("progress-striped").addClass("progress-success");
            $fileItem.find(".qq-upload-cancel").remove();
            $fileItem.find(".qq-upload-status-text").addClass("green-text");
            $fileItem.find(".qq-upload-status-text").html("- Completed");
        }

        if (response.error) {
            $fileItem.find(".progress").removeClass("active").removeClass("progress-info").removeClass("progress-striped").addClass("progress-danger");
            $fileItem.find(".bar").removeClass("bar-success").addClass("bar-danger");
            $fileItem.find(".qq-upload-cancel").remove();
            $fileItem.find(".qq-upload-status-text").addClass("red-text");
            $fileItem.find(".qq-upload-status-text").html("- Upload failed!");
            $("#fineUploader").prepend('<div id="flashMessage" class="alert alert-error"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button><p>Upload failed on <b>'+$fileName+'</b>! Please try uploading it again.</p></div>');
        }

        //check to see if there are any uploads happening still. if not, reload the page use getInProgress() API call
        $uploadingFiles = $(this).fineUploader("getInProgress");

        //close the modal if no uploads are in progress. refresh media index. pop up success banner.
        if ($uploadingFiles < 1) {
            uploads_done();
        }

    }).on('statusChange', function(event, id, oldStatus, newStatus) {
        console.log("ID: "+id+", old status "+oldStatus+", new status "+newStatus);

        var fileName = $fineUploader.fineUploader("getName", id);

        if (newStatus == "submitted") {
            video_submitted();
        }

        //if file size is larger than 500mb then throw an error inside the upload modal that tells them
        if (check_file_size(id) > 524288000 && newStatus == 'submitted') {
            console.log('File size is too big');
            $("#fineUploader").prepend('<div id="flashMessage" class="alert alert-info"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button><p>Just a quick heads up! Your file <b>'+fileName+'</b> is super big (over 500mb). It may take a long time to upload.</p></div>');
        }

        if (newStatus == 'upload successful' && check_for_uploads() == 0 && get_net_uploads() > 0) {
            reset_upload_modal_button(showflash = true);
            //uploads_done();
        }

        if (newStatus == "canceled" && check_for_uploads() == 0 && get_net_uploads() == 0) {
            //reset close button
            reset_upload_modal_button(showflash = false);
            //clear any alerts
            $("#fineUploader").find('.alert-info').remove();
            $("#fineUploader").find('.alert-error').remove();
            $("#fineUploader").prepend("<p class='no-videos'>No videos to upload. :(</p>");
        } else if (newStatus == "canceled" && check_for_uploads() == 0 && get_net_uploads() > 0) {
            //uploads_done();
            reset_upload_modal_button(showflash = true);
           //clear any info alerts
            $("#fineUploader").find('.alert-info').remove();
        }
    }).on('autoRetry', function(event, id, name, attemptNumber) {
        console.log('auto retry fired. id: '+id+', name: '+name+', attempt number: '+attemptNumber);
    });

});
```

And here's my html -

```
<div class="media-thumbnail-view span3 stitched video-dropzone"></div>

<!-- upload video modal -->
<div id="uploadMediaModal" class="modal hide" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Uploading your videos!</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body upload-video-dropzone" id="fineUploader">

  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn upload-video-cancel-btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" data-loading-text="Uploading videos...">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- fineuploader template -->
<script type="text/template" id="qq-template">
    <div class="qq-uploader-selector qq-uploader">
        <div class="qq-upload-drop-area-selector qq-upload-drop-area text-center">
            <p style="margin-bottom:0px;"><small>Drop videos here</small></p>
            <p><small>or</small></p>
            <div class="qq-upload-button-selector btn btn-primary text-center">
                <div>click here to upload</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <ul class="qq-upload-list-selector qq-upload-list" style="margin: 10px 0 0 0; list-style-type: none;">
            <li style="list-style-type: none; margin-bottom:10px;" class="upload-file-list">
                <div class="qq-progress-bar-container-selector progress progress-info progress-striped active">
                    <div class="qq-progress-bar-selector bar bar-success"></div>
                </div>
                <span class="qq-upload-spinner-selector qq-upload-spinner"></span>
                <span class="qq-edit-filename-icon-selector qq-edit-filename-icon"></span>
                <span class="qq-upload-file-selector qq-upload-file"></span>
                <span class="qq-upload-size-selector qq-upload-size"></span>
                <a class="qq-upload-cancel-selector qq-upload-cancel" href="#">Cancel</a>
                <span class="qq-upload-status-text-selector qq-upload-status-text"></span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</script>
```

Comment: Please show YOUR code as well.

Comment: Edited my response and pasted it in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good catch. It appears you uncovered a bug in our build process. What was happening was the jQuery module was not being concatenated into the final build before S3 jQuery module (which depends on the jQuery module). This was fixed in 'develop', and [has been merged](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/commit/68c34ebc8579fd047122f37ad49f55e431977065) into the 'master' branch now.

I would suggest rebuilding either manually or via the [customizer](http://fineuploader.com/customize).

Note that this would not have affected custom builds, only those building via the `grunt package` task. The build generator may have been down at this time and we could have been generating zips on our own using grunt.